# Updating Azure Cloud Service to OS family 6

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-hosted-agent

I am using Azure DevOps to deploy a .Net Web Application. I wanted to update to the new Os Family which is based on Windows 2019 so i can Update my projects to .net framework version 4.7.2 as seen [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-guestos-update-matrix). I have updated my cloud service configuration '.cscfg' file to osFamily="6" but when i try to deploy the app even though the Build succeeds i get this error when i reach the Release step in Azure pipeline:

> The OS family 6 you are trying to deploy is not supported by the SDK package. The SDK package supported OS families:3,4,5,1,2,98,97. Please try to deploy to a different operating system. To do this specify a different osFamily and/or osVersion in your .cscfg file.

I am using the Hosted VS2017 agent.

Comment: For those looking at this, I just re-targeted our cloud services to .NET 4.7.2 and ran a build/pack on HostedVS2017 on Azure DevOps and it worked. Seems they have the new SDK installed now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the error information it indicates that the OS family 6 are not supported by Hosted VS2017 agent.

Based on the link you mentioned that Compatible SDK versions should be Version 2.9.6+.

So my workaround is that you could use the **[Self-host](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azdevops)** agent with latest Azure SDK installed. We could download the latest Azure SDK from this [link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54917).

or you could have a try to install the Azure SDK on the Host 2017 agent (without test)

You also could give your [feedback](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21) to Azure Devops team.